# How do you fire the click event of a iwc:ImageButton in Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a control on my page with the syntax of:

```
 <iwc:ImgButton runat="server" ID="saveForm" ImageUrl="~/images/save.png" OnClientClick="saveFormData(); return false;" Text="Save Form" />
```

which contains some script to fire.  I was was going to have a timer with a confirm box which would remind the person to save.  "It has been X minutes.  Would you like to save?"

When they say ok, It fires off this command:

```
 $("#saveForm").click();
```

but it doesn't seem to fire off the click Function. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ID is that on the server, and isnt nessicarily the answer on the clientside.  To fix it, the jquery command should be:

```
 $("#<%= saveForm.ClientID %>").click();
```

That would resolve it.  Confirmed.